# How to enable specific Ohai plugin on a node in Test Kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, ohai-gem

I wanted to enable Passwd ohai plugin in my node in test kitchen. On a regular node, I've done it by adding:

```
ohai.optional_plugins = [
      :Passwd
]
```

to `/etc/chef/client.rb`.

I wanted to achieve the same in a test node, so I added to my .kitchen.yml:

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  client_rb:
    Ohai::Config[:optional_plugins] =
      - passwd
```

But when I converge the node, the plugin is not enabled. On a test node, in `/home/vagrant/.chef/client.rb` there is no entry about ohai optional plugins and templates that I am using during converge, can not see `node['etc']['group']['SOME_USERNAME']['gid']` attribute (even after second converge, because Ohai have to run first time and then save attributes).

How can I enable Ohai plugin on a test kitchen node?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a working solution?  I'm encountering the [same issue](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/1836).

Comment: Unfortunately not @TrinitronX . I moved on and decided that it is just the way that Test Kitchen operates.

Comment: So as it turns out... my issue was similar yet different (due to another issue presenting itself with the same symptoms).  After tinkering for a while I was able to get `test-kitchen` to output the right format in `client.rb`:  `'ohai.optional_plugins = ': [:Passwd]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an exact answer to your question, but one thing to know is that when running test kitchen, any references to the node object in a recipe under test won't have the actual node object from one run to the next, since it's not being saved back to any chef server. It's kind of a 'clean slate' for each run. You can save the node object to a local file on one run then access it again later, but really can't get changing ohai data from within test kitchen easily in the cookbook as far as I know. You can do something like this to save it and get it in a test:

http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/accessing-chef-node-attributes-from-kitchen-tests

not sure if that's very helpful but I think that fact might be pertinent

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the reason why it was not working for me, even when I `ohai.optional_plugins` added proper line to `client.rb` on a test node. I am marking this as resolved, since this problem is related to the way that Test Kitchen itself operates (as you said, attributes are not being saved back to any chef-server)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
client_rb:
    ohai.optional_plugins: [':Passwd']
```

Comment: This adds `ohai.optional_plugins [:Passwd]` to `/home/vagrant/.chef/client.rb`. But still I can't use attributes like this:

`node['etc']['group']['SOME_USERNAME']['gid']`

in templates. Even if I converge twice (because Ohai needs to run and collect attributes), or add to the begining of the recipe resource "ohai" with action `:reload` to reload Ohai attributes.

How can I verify if the plugin is enabled on the node? The templates that I am using are working on regular nodes with Passwd plugin enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working in recent Chef version `18.0.6` with the following in `.kitchen.yml`:

```yaml
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  client_rb:
    'ohai.optional_plugins = ':
        - :Passwd
```

Including the `=` equals sign in the hash key as a quoted string (`'foo =': bar`) forces `test-kitchen` to template the `client.rb` correctly:

```rb
ohai.optional_plugins =  [:Passwd]
```